Could not be used to start the Task: [The field "Bucket" is not supported by Step Functions] in s3 CompleteMultipartUpload via Step Function
A lambda will start the CreateMultipartUpload and invoke a step function with UploadCopyParts and CompleteMultipartUpload actions.
While executing CompleteMultipartUpload, getting error, could not be used to start the Task: [The field "Bucket" is not supported by Step Functions].
This is the input received by CompleteMultipartUpload action.
{
  "Parts": [
      {
          "PartNumber": 1,
          "Bucket": "dest-bucket",
          "ETag": "\"530cb14bb4720a384a6c973141d\"",
          "UploadId": "my_upload_id",
          "Key": "TEST_ORG_ID/TailNumber/TEST.zip",
          "CopySource": "source-bucket/test.zip?versionId=3ll2UIU3ASPv8"
      },
      {
          "PartNumber": 2,
          "Bucket": "dest-bucket",
          "ETag": "\"998a2dea5ccabcf99wc6ff22c3\"",
          "UploadId": "my_upload_id",
          "Key": "TEST_ORG_ID/TailNumber/TEST.zip",
          "CopySource": "source-bucket/test.zip?versionId=3ll2UIU3ASPv8"
      }
  ]
}

In its configuration section, It will look for these provided API parameters to execute
{
    "Bucket.$": "$.Parts[0].Bucket",
    "Key.$": "$.Parts[0].Key",
    "UploadId.$": "$.Parts[0].UploadId",
    "MultipartUpload": {
      "Parts.$": "$.Parts"
    }
}

We cannot exclude "Bucket" since its a mandatory field for CompleteMultipartUpload. Please help me out
